# Database schema design for financial forecasting

Tags: database, database-design, accounting

I need to develop a web app that allows companies to forecast financials.

the app has different screens, one for defining employee salaries, another for sales projections etc.. 
basically turn an excel financial forecast model into an app.

question is, what would be the best way to design the database, so that financial reports (e.g. a profit and loss statement or balance sheet) could be quickly generated?

- assuming the forecast period is for 5 years, would you have a table
  with 5 years*12 months = 60 fields per each row? is that performant
  enough?
- would you use DB triggers to recalculate salary expenses whenever a single employee data is changed?

Comment: At global scale, you'll find that not every financial sector is driven by months. My first professional programming gig was building software to calculate shareholder value for a multinational corporation. We had to accommodate well over a dozen different accounting periods. I think someplace had 7 per year, but I could be wrong. It was a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think it would be better to store each month's forecast in its own row in a table that looks like this

```
month   forecast
-----   --------
    1      30000
    2      31000
    3      28000
   ...       ...
    60     52000
```

Then you can use the aggregate functions to calculate forecast reports, discounted cash flow etc. ( Like if you want the un-discounted total for just 4 years): 
`SELECT SUM(forecast) from FORECASTS where month=>1 and month<=48`

For salary expenses, I would think that having a view that does calculations on the fly (or if you DB engine supports "materialized views" should have sufficient performance unless we're talking some giant number of employees or really slow DB.

Maybe have a salary history table, that trigger populates when employee data changes/payroll runs

```
employeeId    month   Salary
----------    -----   ------
         1        1     4000
         2        1     3000
         3        1     5000
         1        2     4100
         2        2     3100
         3        2     4800
       ...      ...      ...
```

Then again, you can do SUM or other aggregate function to get to the reported data.

Comment: creating DB views is a clever idea!  The problem is that each month will not have just a single financial value but rather a (user-defined) number of values that need to be calculated for the report. for example: on January I would need to store revenues, cost of revenues, salaries, rent, interest payment etc... this list is dynamic and will change from one model to the next.

Comment: Well, than for each model you can have an `Account Type` table then for  data create a table with Month,AccountType, and AccountValue as columns. So for each month you will have multiple rows, one for each account type. So "Jan 08", 1("Revenues"), $20000 "Jan 08", 2("Costs") $18000 and so on.

Comment: got it. and lastly:  if I need to load all this data into a javascript grid, that expects a json format - how would you generate this json data? specifically the grid would expect something like: {id: 1, data: ["Revenues", "200","210","220", ...]}, {id: 2, data: ["Costs", "50","60","70", ...]}.

Comment: If you really want to do it all in the db you could create a view with a single text column that concatenates all the parameters and json formatting tags. But it might be easier to do in javascript, there's probably some library to format object into json after you load the data - sorry -  javascript is not my wheelhouse.

Comment: And you might have to use pivot to get values onto one row - will depend on what your DB engine supports

Comment: thanks man! I think I will post a follow up question of SE to focus on this sql to json issue.

Comment: Would also probably help to post a specific DB engine, that way actual queries/engine capabilities could be used.